# How to properly excute laravel {{ $chart->id }}_refresh() function

Tags: php, laravel, charts

Hello I am new with Laravel and I am trying to create a dynamic chart and found this link about chart refresh function but I cant figure it out how to execute it properly.

> I just can't figure it out how will I apply this code  `{{ $chart->id }}_refresh(url)` here based on user textbox input.

I already tried a lot but i have no luck in making it work..

I would appreciate any response. Thank you in advance.

Link: https://charts.erik.cat/api_charts.html#update-the-chart-after-rendering

Comment: Can you share more context? How should that "code" be applied after all?

Comment: based on the link I also provided the codes goes something like this:             
var original_api_url = {{ $chart->id }}_api_url;
{{ $chart->id }}_refresh(original_api_url + "?date_start=2019-01-01&date_end=2019-12-31");

Comment: And can you explain what you've tried to use that code, and what exactly does not work yet?

Comment: With this method you can easily refresh data in all charts after selecting a data, or applying a filter. Very useful when your chart needs to display different information regarding to a user input. but I can't figured it out on how to apply it properly

Comment: So, please explain in which context you've tried to use that snippet.